# Facebook login within Android app is redirecting to native Facebook Android app

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am using a latest Facebook sdk in my application to login. Login is working well when the native facebook app is not installed in my device. But if native facebook app is installed then my login is redirected to this native facebook app.

But I want my application to use only facebook dialog to get login. How can I restrict my application to use only Facebook sdk dialog for login?

Below is my sample code for login

code:

```
Session.openActiveSession(MainActivity.this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

              // callback when session changes state



            @Override
              public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

                Log.e("session","open session");

                if (session.isOpened()) {

                    strAccesstoken=session.getAccessToken();
                     List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();

                     Log.e("current permissions",""+permissions);
                        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {

                            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                                    .NewPermissionsRequest(MainActivity.this, PERMISSIONS);
                        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                            return;
                        }

                  // make request to the /me API
                  Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {



                    // callback after Graph API response with user object


                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                        if (user != null) {
                            welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                            welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                            strCurrentuser=user.getId();


                          }

                         // Check for publish permissions    


                    }
                  });
                }
              }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Session.OpenRequest request=new Session.OpenRequest(activity);

request.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
// suppressing single sign on will prevent the native app and use web based login.

Session session= new Session(activity);
session.openForRead(request);
session.setCallback(callback);
Session.setActiveSession(session);
```

Comment: Yes.  this will give you an instance of session..  Then you can use it to make any other request.

Comment: what is this callback? how can I get this.

Comment: session.setCallback( new StatusCallback(){

   @Override
   public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
     Exception exception) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
   } });

Comment: session.setCallback(callback) is not there under session (undefined method in session)

Comment: session.setCallback(callback).  in place of callback use new StatusCallback(){ // your code}

Comment: @Override

        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {

                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(activity, requestCode, resultCode, data);

            }

Comment: everything is done but its not working,I can able to display login dialog but after that nothing is happening

Comment: Did u override the OnActivityResult

Answer (score 0):

Also dont forget to override onActivityResult

```
@Override

        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {

                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(activity, requestCode, resultCode, data);

            }
```